Chart.js LinearScale declaration in Import statement throws warning in VS Code
I have working v4.4.6 Chart.js code implemented in vanilla JS. It's using an import statement for tree shaking thus:
import {Chart, LineController, LineElement, PointElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, Filler} from "chart.js"; (the full path to "chart.js" is specified in an import map)
I then have the following registrations later in the code just before I build the chart:
Chart.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, Filler);
It all works fine, but VS code is greying out LinearScale in the import statement with the warning 'LinearScale' is declared but its value is never read. ts(6133).
If I remove LinearScale from either the import or registration statements, (or both), then the chart breaks with the error "linear" is not a registered scale as you would expect. So clearly LinearScale is being used somewhere, but VS Code thinks it isn't? All the other imports and registrations work fine with no warnings. What could be happening here please, and how would I remove this warning? Here's the relevant map code:
    const elCanvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    const data = {
        labels: arLabels,
        datasets: [{
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: arData,
            backgroundColor: function(context) {
                const chart = context.chart;
                const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;
                if (!chartArea) {
                  // This case happens on initial chart load
                  return;
                }
                return getGradient(elCanvas, ctx, chartArea);
            },
            fill: true,
            pointRadius: 0,  // removes rounded blobby peaks
            cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'  // prevents smoothing of peaks
        }]
    };

    const options = {
        scales: {
            x: {        
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return `${this.getLabelForValue(value)} Km`;
                    }
                }
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return `${this.getLabelForValue(value)} m`;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: false
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: options
    };

    Chart.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, Filler);
    new Chart(elCanvas, config);


there is an way that is shorter syntax and might remove the syntax error is ```import { Chart, registerables} from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);``` reference

Thanks for the suggestion. Weirdly, that approach import { Chart, registerables} is not in the v4 documentation. But it seems to be the exact same as doing  import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';. When I test all 3  methods, I get the exact same number and size of files downloaded.  So I don't think tree-shaking is working for my chart, perhaps because it's very simple, so it's all in the base class file. But your method does stop the VS code warning.

The LinearScale class is not accessed by name in the code of Chart.js, but through the registry, based on its static id, linear, therefore it's quite normal that typescript will not detect its being used there. However, I am puzzled by the fact that the call to Chart.register(....., LinearScale, .....) doesn't count as reading the class.

the question was to remove the vscode warning since the code works fine because then i wil make an answer that is an combination of mine and kikons

Yes, my code works fine. My question is really about why VS code is showing the warning and if I can remove it without resorting to a generic import which will pull in more code than I need. Only LinearScale pops warnings when written as an individual import. Neither of the generic importing methods (chart.js/auto or {Chart, …registerables) show any such warning, so it’s just a small weird edge case, I guess?
